# How to pass an argument to the subprocess that expects input

Tags: python, git, subprocess, stdin, ssh-agent

I would like to execute a `"git push"` command using Python script. I was hoping to achieve this by using python's `subprocess.Popen()` method. However when I invoke the `"git push"` command, the **ssh agent** asks me for my **passphrase** in order to be able to push any changes to the repository.

And here is my question - is there any way for me to be able to pass my passphrase which is an input expected by the ssh process not the git itself?

```
    process = subprocess.Popen("git push", stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=False)
    pin = process.stdin.write("Passphrase")
```

I acknowledge that it might be easier to get rid of this **ssh-agent's** passphrase message everytime I `git push` or `pull`, however just for the sake of knowing I was curious is there a way to achieve it this way.

Comment: In some cases you can use a pty and create a session, so that `/dev/tty` refers to your program's pty pair. However, ssh agent may send the passphrase request through to *another machine*, in which case there's literally no way to trap this on your machine, as it's not actually occurring on your machine in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Note that [GitPython issue 559](https://github.com/gitpython-developers/GitPython/issues/559) mentioned in 2016:

> As far as I know, it is not possible to use keys with passphrases with GitPython due to the way git is invoked by it.
> It simply does not connect standard input, which usually would be required to read the passphrase. The preferred way to do it would be to use a specific key without passphrase.
>
> If that is not an option, git will also invoke the program pointed to by `GIT_ASKPASS` to read a password for use with the ssh key.

There is however a possible workaround, initially applied to GPG:

[**How to sign commits using the GitPython package**](https://github.com/Nautilus-Cyberneering/pygithub/blob/main/docs/how_to_sign_commits_using_the_gitpython_package.md)

See [`03_sign_commit_using_the_gitpython_package.py`](https://github.com/Nautilus-Cyberneering/pygithub/blob/4d87441917d8131480e2b25a36cdb6320d1e49c8/src/03_sign_commit_using_the_gitpython_package.py).
But again, for GPG. Check if that can be adapted for SSH.